# UICollectionView NSFetchedResultsController create section and move item into it

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView with core data and NSFetchedResultsController.

When a cell is selected I want to move it into a different section at the top of the collection view. The problem is that the section might not have been added yet. I basically need to add a new section when a cell is selected before I move the cell into the new section.

See below -

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are going about this in the wrong way. If I were you I would try to delete the object and then reinsert it with the correct section key.

So, if your NSManagedObject has a section-key of 1 you will need to store the objects values locally whilst you delete the object.  Then you can create a new record with the stored values and update the section-key to 0.

This should remove the old cell and insert a new one in a new section.

See below -

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *obj = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *name = obj.name;

    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:task];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    NSManagedObject *newObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"entityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    [newObj setValue:name forKey:@"name"];

    [self.managedObjectContext newObj];

    error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this it seems an obvious way to go, and it's working well!

Comment: This does not seem a good solution to me. If you have a fetched results controller using the `sectionNameKeyPath:` parameter to group the results into sections, then something like `[obj setValue:@(newSectionNumber) forKey:@"sectionNumber"]` should be sufficient to move the object to a different section automatically.